# String Split in R Studio

Tags: r

Can anyone help me as I am trying to split the date from a string and the word "football" from the date in R?

Before 30/8/2020football

After 30/8/2020 in a date format and "football" as a string

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data:

```
v <- '30/8/2020football'
```

Solution:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = format(as.Date(unlist(strsplit(sub('([0-9/]+)(football).*', '\\1 \\2', v), " "))[1], "%d/%m/%Y")),
                 String = unlist(strsplit(sub('([0-9/]+)(football).*', '\\1 \\2', v), " "))[2])
```

Result:

```
df
        Date   String
1 2020-08-30 football
```

Or, if you prefer a more transparent procedure:

First split the vector:

```
v_split <- unlist(strsplit(sub('([0-9/]+)(football).*', '\\1 \\2', v), " "))
```

Then set up the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = format(as.Date(v_split [1], "%d/%m/%Y")),
  String = v_split [2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way based on information you have provided :

```
string <- '30/8/2020football'
date <- sub('(\\d+\\d+\\d+).*', '\\1', string)
remaining_string <- sub('.*\\d+(.*)', '\\1', string)
remaining_string
#[1] "football"
date <- as.Date(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
date
#[1] "2020-08-30"
```